# Как защитить видео от копирования?

Tags: java, видео, online-video

Реализовываю платный видео сервис. Стоит вопрос безопасности и защиты видео от копирования.

У меня была мысль разделить видео и аудио отдельно (у нас несколько звуковых дорожек, я бы не хотел бы кодировать их в видео). Но как реализовать синхронизацию, что бы она работала без задержек и не потерять при этом кроссплатформенность системы. Может кто-то уже реализовывал подобное.
Помогите советом, возможно уже есть плеер где реализована эта функция.

Comment: А потом юзверь с mplayer легко и непринужденно объединит аудио и видео ;-)

Comment: Там будет иная система защиты :) Не так просто.

Comment: Что мешает пользователю записать видео с экрана и звук с микшера ОС в процессе воспроизведения?

Comment: Поверх видео, будут выводится данные пользователя - телефон, имя и фамилия. Будет понятно кто записал видео и кому адресовать  претензию.

Comment: @Alexsandr +79000000000 Вася Пупкин? И сотрётся в любом видеоредакторе? :)

Comment: Вы будете на лету декодить/енкодить видео с телефоном поверх него? Я открою 10 вкладок и ваш сервис ляжет от нагрузки на цп :)

Comment: Система защиты будет на уровне wistia. Нужно хорошо будет заморочиться что бы скачать файл.